# xcode 9.1 cannot jump to definition

Tags: swift, xcode, ide, xcode9.1

I have only one large project write with swift 3.2 and use Xcode 9.1 to open it.
But I can't use function "Jump to definition" of Xcode, it only show question mark (?).
The other project can "Jump to definition".
How can I fix it?
Very thanks.

Comment: This usually happens when the indexing is not done yet or has stopped because of an error. You may want to try cleaning the project - maybe even cleaning the derived data. Search how to do this there's many explanations.

Comment: Sometimes restarting Xcode and a clean build can solve the problem as well.

Comment: if I open in xcode 8.3.3, "Jump to definition" will work, but xcode 9.1 doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences->Navigation->Command-click on Code:->Jump To Definition

See the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Force Quit Xcode -> Start Xcode -> Clean Build Folder

Let the indexing finish and files getting processed.

Run the build again.